# Symfony doctrine:fixtures:load give ContextErrorException, Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I can't figure out what's happening here. 
I'm trying to add fixtures on a symfony project, nothing strange, fixtures seems to be well formed, and the console command :

```
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test
```

find my fixtures but don't want to load it since it say :

```
# php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --env=test
Careful, database will be purged. Do you want to continue y/N ?y
> purging database
> loading Covoituragesimple\AnnonceBundle\DataFixtures\ORM\AppFixtures

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]  
Notice: Undefined variable: EjehHi1ubBYApRfaNZnEo
```

I have no more idea where to looks ? 
What to search ? Where it comes from ? 
How to solve it ?

What I tried : 
I try to delete the oneToOne and oneToMany relations -->deosn't seem to change anything)

ps: I use the version of doctrine-fixtures-bundle "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.*" (i was not abble to use the last one since i use symfony-framework-bundle 3.2.13 and the last version of doctrine-fixtures ask for 3.3+).

Comment: can you please show your code?

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVED] Aoutch ! Ok my bad, my bad.
The [rubber duck debbuging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) helped me to fix it.

```
$client = new Client();
$client->setName("clienttest");
$client->setEmail("clienttest@provider.com");
$client->setUsername("clienttest");
$client->setDisplayname("clienttest");
$client->setSignaturemail("blablabla.<br />");
$client->setPassword("$2y$10$EjehHi1ubBYApRfaNZnEo.aQ/aZIiTJdY2sPetVWj7P7/yQNfhe7a");
$manager->persist($client);
$manager->flush();
```

I used double quote instead of simple quote, so php was trying to interpret the bcrypt hash of the password and told me that the var $EjehH.... doesn't exist (which is true).

Replacing double quote with single quote solved the problem.

```
$client->setPassword('$2y$10$EjehHi1ubBYApRfaNZnEo.aQ/aZIiTJdY2sPetVWj7P7/yQNfhe7a');
```

Thanks for help.